# How to block AAAA answers for certain domains using RPZ?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ipv6, rpz

Is it possible to block AAAA answers being sent back to clients from a local dns server, but only for certain forward dns domains?
I know I can do the filtering based on ipv6 subnet (working sample below), but i would like to filter out based on domain.

I.e. google services (1e100.net domain) are much faster over ipv4 transport, yet i'd still like to have ipv6 for everything else.

```
;this RPZ entry successfully blocks AAAA answers that match 2001:db8:aa::/48
48.zz.aa.db8.2001.rpz-ip       IN      CNAME   .
```

My local DNS server in question is running bind 9.9.5

Comment: You must have some seriously strange connectivity. In most of the world Google services are much faster over IPv6.

Comment: It's not native ipv6, so the path is a bit suboptimal, i.e. I cannot benefit from a local Internet eXchange point.. But I've had cases where v6 had better throughout.